# Hide DIV when certain item gets selected from Dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net

i think the title explains it already.

can someone point me to the right direction? thanks!

EDIT:

Sorry forgot to tell that it has to be client-side

Comment: If it has to be on client side, you should not tag it with asp.net and C#. Tag with javascript instead

Comment: possible duplicate of [Show|Hide Div depending on show DropDownList](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4900475/showhide-div-depending-on-show-dropdownlist)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4900475/showhide-div-depending-on-show-dropdownlist) question. Questioner wants to achieve the same thing you want

Answer (score 0):

make div as run at server and access it on code behind as name. Set display property of style when dropdown list selection is posted back.

Comment: This can easily be handled using javascript and then won't require a post back. Doing a postback just to hide a div isn't going to lead to a great user experience.

Comment: @Bencr: but it`s the straightforward way to do it. If he needs more to do than simply handle the visibility(f.e. databinding) than he needs a  postback anyway.

Comment: He only asked about visibility and the other answers weren't posted when I down voted. Don't worry, I'll down vote them all. @tim is it the best way to do it?

Comment: @Tim, come on, I gave my reason for the downvote and aside from that, the answer is poorly formatted and not even correct "access it on code behind as name". What does that even mean? "Set display property of style when dropdown list selection is posted back." if it was `runat=server` then you'd just set the visibility.

Answer (score 0):

If you use client script you won't have to perform a server round trip.

This forum post does almost exactly what you want but for a text box instead of a div.

http://forums.asp.net/t/1224793.aspx/1?Javascript+for+onchange+event+in+asp+dropdownlist

Comment: can you point me to a tutorial on using javascript? like where to put them and all the basics? i've been scouring and can't find sites with good examples